# Wscript.exe task stacks and stresses CPU

Tags: javascript, activex, wsh

## **SOLVED:**

#### I realized, that the process 'wscript.exe' is not essential to keep the program running if you let it sleep, so I just kill it with a batch file within the script after the ActiveXObject has been initiated.

I've installed Realterm which for me acts as a RS485 Client.
Works like a charm but doesn't allow saving settings as a preset. So everytime you start it, you'd have to put in your settings again and again which is a pain in the butt for me.

They've got a somewhat 'easy' way to handle this by letting you write a script, that instantiates the ActiveXObject (yeah, pretty old huh...) and predefine some settings, like the COM-Port, Baud Rate etc.

This is their provided demo of what the script should look like:

```
var RT = new ActiveXObject("realterm.realtermintf");
RT.caption="Windows Scripting Host Demo";
RT.HalfDuplex=1;
RT.baud=57600;
RT.FlowControl=2; //2=RTS/CTS
RT.Port=1;
RT.PortOpen=1;
RT.LinefeedIsNewline=1;
RT.SelectTabSheet("I2C");

RT.PutString("G1"); 
RT.NewlineTerminal();
WScript.Sleep(500);

RT.PutString("SB20DP SB302P"); 
RT.NewlineTerminal();
WScript.Sleep(500);
RT.PutString("SB20DP SB302P"); 
//RT.PutChar(10); //LF
RT.NewlineTerminal();

WScript.Echo("Realterm will close when you click OK");

RT.Close();
```

By having you click the 'OK' on the popup that

> WScript.Echo("Realterm will close when you click OK");

instantiates, the '**.Close()**' method is called and the window is closed correctly.

- The problem/inconvenience is that there will be a popup always open if you'd go with the demo. I would like to have the convenience to just close the window and task by clicking on the red X on the window form.

This is my current code and way of going about the inconvenience.

```
var RT = new ActiveXObject("realterm.realtermintf");
RT.caption="Realterm Mod";
RT.HalfDuplex=1;
RT.baud=9600;
RT.FlowControl=0; //2=RTS/CTS
RT.Port=16;
RT.PortOpen=0;
RT.LinefeedIsNewline=1;
RT.SelectTabSheet("Send");
 
RT.NewlineTerminal();


while (true){
    
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    
    if(hours >= 16 && minutes >= 0){ //closes if certain time is met
        WScript.Echo("Feierabend!")
        RT.Close();
    }
    else{ // keeps the program from closing
        continue;
    }
}
```

Problem now: If you were to force it open by putting in a while (true) - loop and **NOT** use the popup way of going about it, when you close the window by clicking the red X on the form, **the window closes** but the '**wscript.exe**' task **stays open** and keeps your CPU busy. The task also stacks if you were to close and reopen the program.

My question is:

- Is there any way you could catch the closing of the window before it happens or check if it was closed and either then do ' **.Close()** ' on the object itself or **call a batch file** that kills the task?

I don't have that much experience with WScript, hence I have no idea if you could even handle events like that.
This generally is more of a exercise/gimmick for me than a real problem because I'm learning to code and want to understand more and have a bigger knowledge of things, so I'd appreciate actual answers to the problem.

Thanks to you all in advance!

Comment: You haven't really stated a problem.

Comment: The problem/inconvenience is that there will be a popup always open if you'd go with the demo. I would like to have the convenience to just close the window and task by clicking on the red X of the form.

Comment: Where is the while loop? You've wrapped the example code in a loop?

Comment: You can run a wscript from the terminal. In that case, use cscript. It may or may not help your cause.

Comment: @Teemu i will add my current code.

Comment: @GetSet how would that help the problem of having some window still open? from my understanding, cscript does the same as wscript but in the DOS-Box instead of dialog boxes.

Comment: C-script won't show any dialog boxes. Omit `echo` (if you don't want the message box to appear), remove `else`, and add `break;` after the line `RT.Close();`. If the wsh script still runs after executing, we'd need to see how the script is called.

Comment: @Teemu well, isn't it logical that it still runs? Because the if-condition is only met at a certain time, wouldn't it mean that the task only closes at that certain time? I've only put that in, because that was the only way I could think of controlling when it closes.

Comment: The while loop is still running, wsh is run in its own thread. Just break the loop, then the wsh execution can be finished. You can add `WScript.Quit();` as the last line of the script too.

Comment: ?? Currently there's no breakpoint. I didn't say "remove if", I said "_remove else_", it's useless, the loop will continue anyway until the `while` condition becomes falsy. Only that the `if` condition seems odd, on the midnight it takes 16 hours to terminate the loop ...

Comment: @Teemu the getHours() checks the current time and I match it against the condition of hours >= 16. thats my end of work lol. as i said, just a gimmick and temporary substitute for controlling when it closes. Putting a break after the RT.Close() doesn't do anything yet because it doesn't even reach that point. And sadly the problem of the open task is still there.

Comment: Why it wouldn't reach the break line? I think the problem is the while loop itself. It consumes resources during your work hours. You could spawn `setTimeout` object from Internet Explorer, and set a timeout to close RT and terminate the wsh script. I don't remember how to spawn the object off my head, but I'll dig it out, it just takes a couple of hours, I'm currently on work.

Comment: Well, do you mean after the RT.Close() within the if-statement or the line after the if-statement within the loop? All good, no stress.

Comment: Within the `if` block, after `RT.Close()` (it just closes RT, it doesn't terminate wsh script) , or you can replace `break` with `WScript.Quit()` as well. But the actual problem is the resource consuming while the `while` loop runs, you've to get rid of that.

Comment: [sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//6t81adfd(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) might be a solution too (instead of spawning objects from IE). Just calculate the time left to 16:00, and make wsh to sleep that time, then close RT, and terminate wsh. The wsh script will run all the day, but its resource consumption is minimal.

Comment: @Teemu something like this? : 
 `var calcSleepHours = 16 - currentHour - 1; 
 var calcSleepMinutes = 60 - currentMinutes;
 calcSleep = calcSleepHours * 3600000 + calcSleepMinutes * 60000
 WScript.Sleep(calcSleep);`

Comment: Something like that, and after `WScript.Sleep(calcSleep);` just add `RT.Close();` and `WScript.Quit();`. You could test with a small timeout, though.